# difference between 2 files and get the changes

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have 2 files 1st one is original data and 2nd one is after some modification (eg - network/storage level). So I want to compare 1st file with new one and create a file with what new added / modified lines.

for eg:

file1 - original file
Route table:

```
Route table:
10.208.85.0/26 dev eth3 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.108.12
148.89.140.0/22 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0
148.89.168.0/21 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0
151.87.44.0/23 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0
151.87.46.0/23 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0
192.55.16.128/28 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0
192.55.28.32/27 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0
192.55.28.64/28 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0
192.55.192.96/27 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0
192.60.136.0/22 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0
192.62.212.64/26 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0

Disks:
Disk /dev/sda: 96 GiB, 103079215104 bytes, 201326592 sectors
/dev/sda1  *       2048   1060863   1058816  517M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1060864 201326591 200265728 95.5G 8e Linux LVM
```

file2 - Modified

```
Route table:
10.208.85.0/26 dev eth3 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.108.12
10.123.17.64/26 via 10.1.208.1 dev eth2
148.89.140.0/22 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0
148.89.168.0/21 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0
151.87.44.0/23 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0
151.87.46.0/23 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0
192.55.16.128/28 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0
192.55.28.32/27 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0
192.55.28.64/28 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0
192.55.192.96/27 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0
192.60.136.0/22 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0
192.62.212.64/26 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0

Disks:
Disk /dev/sda: 128 GiB, 137438953472 bytes, 201326592 sectors
/dev/sda1  *       2048   1060863   1058816  517M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1060864 201326591 200265728 95.5G 8e Linux LVM
```

I am looking an output something  like (another file )

```
Added : 10.123.17.64/26 via 10.1.208.1 dev eth2
Modified : Disk /dev/sda: 128 GiB, 137438953472 bytes, 201326592 sectors
```

Please help

Comment: Hi `vijayedm` the question is not clear can you elaborate this further so that community members can answer your queries. Are you looking for something like compare each line of the two files and concatenate the output in a new file. for example
compare IP addr1 with IP addr2 and write in a third file like
IP addr1
IP addr2
correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: At this level of exposition, sounds like you are simply looking for the `diff` command. If not, please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: 2 files , 1st one have the data and after some modification 2nd file generated. So need to compare with 1st file, what are the modification done on 2nd file. this for a script to check pre and post validation after a server reboot. 


Requirement is check the difference with file one and if any new lines added /modified that need to be displayed in another file, from the example one line modified and another added , so I want a output file like this

[added - 10.123.17.64/26 via 10.1.208.1 dev eth2]
[Modified - Disk /dev/sda: 128 GiB, 137438953472 bytes, 201326592 sectors]

Answer (score 1):

As starting point, you can use `difflib`:

```
from difflib import Differ

with (open('file1.txt') as file_1,
      open('file2.txt') as file_2):
    differ = Differ()
    for line in differ.compare(file_1.readlines(), file_2.readlines()):
        if line[0] in list('+-?'):
            print(line.strip())
```

Output:

```
+ 10.123.17.64/26 via 10.1.208.1 dev eth2
- Disk /dev/sda: 96 GiB, 103079215104 bytes, 201326592 sectors
?                ^^       - -   -----
+ Disk /dev/sda: 128 GiB, 137438953472 bytes, 201326592 sectors
?                ^^^         +++ ++++
```

Answer (score 1):

In linux you can use `diff` to compare files line by line.
Let us consider the 2 example files provided in your question.

**The Command:**

```
diff /tmp/file1.txt /tmp/file2.txt
```

**The Output:**

```
2a3
> 10.123.17.64/26 via 10.1.208.1 dev eth2
15c16
< Disk /dev/sda: 96 GiB, 103079215104 bytes, 201326592 sectors
---
> Disk /dev/sda: 128 GiB, 137438953472 bytes, 201326592 sectors
```

**The Command to generate the desired output:**

```
diff /tmp/file1.txt /tmp/file2.txt | sed -e ':begin;$!N;s/---\n>/Modified: /;tbegin' -e 's/>/Added: /g' | egrep 'Added|Modified'
```

**The Desired Output:**

```
Added:  10.123.17.64/26 via 10.1.208.1 dev eth2
Modified:  Disk /dev/sda: 128 GiB, 137438953472 bytes, 201326592 sectors
```